# Character spacing issue on different screens in Android

Tags: java, android, fonts

I am using `Franchise-Bold.ttf` for my application. I am facing this issue where on High xhdpi resolution screen the text appear perfect without any spacing. like this:

[image: XHDPI]

But on normal or Hdpi screen show spacing without any reason. I want to remove these spaces. How can I do this?

[image: Normal/HDPI]

Comment: Most likely some variant of https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39755. Not sure if there is a solution, though.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like font size issue.
can you try to us `sp` instead of normal font. Use this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/design/style/typography.html).